# ddrescue on CygWin creates a zero size image

Tags: image, cygwin

I try to create an image of a disk (USB flash key) in CygWin with use of the `ddrescue` command. I do the following:
first, with the command `df` I look where the disks are in CygWin. 
Τhe output is:

```
C:                 30716276     30489824   226452          100% /cygdrive/c
D:                 56323856     55794432   529424          100% /cygdrive/d
F:               1953480700   1927260140 26220560           99% /cygdrive/f
H:                  7847904       140324  7707580            2% /cygdrive/h
```

Then, to create the image of the disk `h:/` I run the command like this:

```
ddrescue -v -n /cygdrive/h f:/___buffer/discoH.img discoH.log
```

The program works some time and is likely reading the disk. Αs a result, the file 
`f:/___buffer/discoH.img` is really created but

*its size is zero!*

I tried some variations of the command options but with the same result. The disk to be read is fully working and readable, now I only want to learn to create its image.
When using `ddrescue` under true Linux (Ubuntu), the non-zero-size image of the same disk is created without any problem. What could be the cause for the fail in CygWin?
I still work in Windows XP SP3 32bit, the version of CygWin is

```
$ uname -r
2.0.4(0.287/5/3)
$ uname -m
i686 (32bit)
```

On another computer, with Windows 8, the result is the same. Probably, I lack doing  something elementary?

PS the disk I want to image is 8GB, and there are 26GB of free space on the disk `f:/` where I want to create the image

Answer (score 1):

`/cygdrive/h` is not a disk image. Try with `/dev/sdX`

You can identify the X letter, from

```
$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name   win-mounts
8     0 976762584 sda
8     1 960658432 sda1   D:\
8     2  16102400 sda2   E:\
8    16 250059096 sdb
8    17    266240 sdb1
8    18     16384 sdb2
8    19 248765440 sdb3   C:\
8    20   1003520 sdb4
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you matzeri ! Yours was really the elementary thing I needed but did not know.
So, I use the command `cat /proc/partitions` instead of `df`, get the disk reference
`sdc1` instead of `/cygdrive/h`, run the command

`ddrescue -v -n /dev/sdc1 f:/___buffer/discoH.img discoH.log`

instead of the one I indicated above in my question text, and it works! The image is being recorded

Comment: `sdc1` is the image of the first partition. The full disk is `sdc`